# Logical Question

Tags: c++, matlab, logic

Consider a [4x8] matrix "A" and [1x8] matrix "B". I need to check if there exists a value "X" such that

```
[A]^T * [X] = [B]^T  exists for any x >= 0 { X is a [4X1] matrix,  T = transpose }
```

Now here is the trick/tedious part. The matrix A always has 1 as its diagonal. `A11,A22,A33,A44 = 1` This matrix can be considered as two halves with first half being the first 4 columns and the second half being the second 4 columns like something below :

```
        1 -1 -1 -1   1 0 0 1
  A =  -1  1 -1  0   0 1 0 0
       -1 -1  1  0   1 0 0 0 
       -1 -1 -1  1   1 1 0 0
```

Each row in the first half can have either two or three -1's and if it has two -1's then that corresponding row in the second half should have one "1" or if any row has three -1's the second half of the matrix should have two 1's. The overall objective is to have the sum of each row to be 0.

Now B is a [1x8] matrix which can also be considered as two halves as follows:

```
B = -1 -1 0 0   0 0 1 1
```

Here there can be either one, two, three or four -1's in the first half and there should be equal number of 1's in the second half. It should be done in combinations For example, if there are two -1's in the first half, they can be placed in 4 choose 2 = 6 ways and for each of them there will be 6 ways to place the 1's in the second half which has a total of 6*6 = 36 ways. i.e. 36 different values for B's if there are two -1's in the first half. The placement of 1's in the matrix A should also be the same way. The way I could think of doing this is to consider a `valarray` or something of that sort and make the matrices A and B but I don't know what to do.

Now for every A, I've to test it with every combinations of B to see if there exists

```
[A]^T * [X] = [B]^T
```

I'm trying to prove a result that I got I need to know if such an X would exist or not. I'm very confused on implementing this. Any suggestions are welcome. This would come under linear programming concept in math. I want it either in C++ or in Matlab. Any other languages are also acceptable but I'm familiar with only these two. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Here is my answer for this problem :

```
clear;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%# Generating all possible values of vector B

%# permutations using dec2bin (start from 17 since it's the first solution)
vectorB = str2double(num2cell(dec2bin(17:255)));

%# changing the sign in the first half, then check that the total is zero
vectorB(:,1:4) = - vectorB(:,1:4);
vectorB = vectorB(sum(vectorB,2)==0,:);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%# generate all possible variation of first/second halves
z = -[0 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 0; 1 1 1]; n = -sum(z,2);
h1 = {
    [         ones(4,1) z(:,1:3)] ;
    [z(:,1:1) ones(4,1) z(:,2:3)] ;
    [z(:,1:2) ones(4,1) z(:,3:3)] ;
    [z(:,1:3) ones(4,1)         ] ;
};
h2 = arrayfun(@(i) unique(perms([zeros(1,4-i) ones(1,i)]),'rows'), (1:2)', ...
    'UniformOutput',false);

%'# generate all possible variations of complete rows
rows = cell(4,1);
for r=1:4
    rows{r} = cell2mat( arrayfun( ...
        @(i) [ repmat(h1{r}(i,:),size(h2{n(i)-1},1),1) h2{n(i)-1} ], ...
        (1:size(h1{r},1))', 'UniformOutput',false) );
end

%'# generate all possible matrices (pick one row from each to form the matrix)
sz = cellfun(@(M)1:size(M,1), rows, 'UniformOutput',false);
[X1 X2 X3 X4] = ndgrid(sz{:});
matrices = cat(3, ...
    rows{1}(X1(:),:), ...
    rows{2}(X2(:),:), ...
    rows{3}(X3(:),:), ...
    rows{4}(X4(:),:) );
matrices = permute(matrices, [3 2 1]);              %# 4-by-8-by-104976
A = matrices;
clear matrices X1 X2 X3 X4 rows h1 h2 sz z n r
options = optimset('LargeScale','off','Display','off');
for i = 1:size(A,3),
    for j = 1:size(vectorB,1),
        X = linprog([],[],[],A(:,:,i)',vectorB(j,:)');
        if(size(X,1)>0)  %# To check that it's not an empty matrix
            if((size(find(X < 0),1)== 0)) %# to check the condition X>=0
                if (A(:,:,i)'* X == (vectorB(j,:)'))                
                    X
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I got it with the help of stackoverflow folks. The only problem is the linprog function throws a lot of exceptions in every iteration along with the answers produced. The exception is:

```
(1)Exiting due to infeasibility: an all-zero row in the constraint matrix does not have a zero in corresponding right-hand-side entry. 
(2) Exiting: One or more of the residuals, duality gap, or total relative error has stalled: the primal appears to be infeasible (and the dual unbounded).(The dual residual < TolFun=1.00e-008.
```

What does this mean. How can I overcome this?

Comment: is X a vector - then its a System of linear equations.  Otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: you can use least squares to get rough solution or remove linear dependence to hopefully get 4x4 matrix or brute force it after getting into "upper" form.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system

Comment: Matlab and programming in general is not very suited for proofs...

Comment: 'linprog' function in matlab could easily solve this but I'm stuck in generationg the combinations. :(

Comment: @Sun you are doing it the wrong way.  Read about overdetermined systems and when they have infinite solutions or no solutions.

Comment: @aaa: Why do you think so. X is an [8X1] matrix and I don't think it is overdetermined. is it?

Comment: the system is:  you are essentially finding 4 vars given 8 constraints.  read wiki page carefully.

Comment: Aaaa: I'm trying to find 8 vars here, right?

Comment: @Sun your X must be [ x, y, z, w ] - 4 not 8 vector.

Comment: @aaa: I'm confused here. What I'm trying to do is to find A'[8x4] * X[8x1] = B'[8x1]. So if i have A and B in matlab if A'*pinv(A')*B' returns B' then I've a solution X, right ?

Comment: @Sun `A'[8x4] * X[8x1] = B'[4x1], A'[4x8] * X[4x1] = B'[8x1]`

Comment: I get it. Thanks a bunch. Also I think you meant A'[8x4] in the second equation too.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if you are familiar with [system linear equations and their solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations), or it is what you are trying to "invent". See also [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f4-983672.html) for Matlab-specific explanation.

If you are familiar with that, you should be more clear in your question about what makes your problem different.